How do I add a single existing class to a class diagram in visual studio?
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and would like to add an existing c# class to a class diagram.
Dragging the class from the solution explorer to the diagram always gives me a no-no cursor.
Do I have to manually edit the cd-file?

You can drag script files or project files to the diagram.

Is the application still running?

@shingo: Thanks, that put me on the right track, see my answer below.
OlivierJacot-Descombes: No, I was not in debug mode.
Also, I wonder why my question was downvoted without leaving any comment on why.

Apparently you have to drag a source code file from the solution explorer to a diagram. If the file contains multiple classes, all will be added.
If I only want to add one class, I have to remove all others manually from the diagram after adding the whole file.

Usually I have one class == one file. Therefore, I assumed that you were dragging a class file. Please add a clarification to your question about wanting to add one class from a multi class source file.
